# Protect public RSA key during transit

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

**Clarification: My question relates to setting up a "secure" communication channel between two parties where a key (read passphrase) has been agreed upon in the real world. Only using RSA allows for MITM-attacks  (if I'm not misstaken), so I was thinking encrypting the public keys with AES (the key that both have agreed upon) before sending them to respective parties **

I'm currently trying to build two applications that talks with eachother. To secure the exchanged messages I was thinking on using RSA where each application has it's own set of keys.

Before communication is started between the two applications they do need to exchange keys. That shouldn't be a problem but I was thinking on using AES to encrypt the public keys before sending them over the internet.

I know what the word public (as in public key) means but I was thinking that this would see to that the right application/computer gets the key and no one else.

So I want to exchange keys and to protect them from MITM attacks.

If anybody could give a better suggestion (I'm using the LibCrypto library btw), I'm all ears.

Thank you.

Best regards
/Tomas Gustavsson

Comment: Why do you go to asymmetric encryption if you've already got a pre-established symmetric secret key? What you need it some way to create AES session keys, preferably one that is not vulnerable to MITM attacks and does not expose your master key to danger. But I think this is the wrong forum for this, try crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, and a passphrase is not a key. It can be converted *to* a key, e.g. using a password based key derivation function like PBKDF2 but it's not the same. Using your password as a key may, for instance, lead to related key attacks.

Comment: OK, looked it up, probably the password as key can still not be used as a related key attack, but you are certainly restricting the password to the key size, which means you are also restricting the key space (the number of keys to search in brute force attacks for instance).

Answer (score 1):

This question shows many misconceptions from your part.

> I know what the word public (as in public key) means but I was
>   thinking that this would see to that the right application/computer
>   gets the key and no one else.

I think this is the real problem you have and ask.
Which I think is: How can you know that you are using the public key of the entity you actually want to communicate with and not the public key of a malicious entity claiming to be the who you want to communicate with?

This problem is solved in a typical installation by certificates signed by a trusted authority **and issued to the specific entity** i.e. IP or DNS name.

In your case you haven't given any details of your certificates.

You could just as well manually pre-install them and use them for your secure connections.

If you follow some other plan e.g. symmetric encryption then your would start asking other questions e.g. how do you securely share the secret key etc

Comment: There are no certainties on the web, that I know. But if both parties have agreed on a AES-key (perhaps in bar, a mall or some other real life locations) they use this encryption key to encrypt and decrypt eachothers public key which they are sending to eachother.

If the attacker doesn't know the AES-key he possibly can't send me a public key which I will accept (as it can't be decrypted and validated as a valid public key). Isn't this correct?

Comment: @ tomplast:Well in this case they could easily exchange their public keys as well and avoid the overhead of AES encryption alltogether. Note that the example you now mention falls into my more generic: `manuall pre-installation` mentioned in my answer

Comment: Sorry I guess I need to be a little more specific. The two applications are actually two persons communicating via text messages. They can't trust a third party and their only means of trust is a AES-key they have agreed upon in the real world. Each session started between the two parties are supposed to use new generated keys each time, and that includes their agreed AES-key (perhaps LaDo34MooMooTakida$ or some more harder to guess password). So both parties should be able communicate "secure" without risking a MITM attack.